# How to generate views and services with MEAN.IO?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, mean.io

One of the cool things about the angular-yeoman generator is the ability to create views, directives and services via command line. Does the MEAN stack have this capability or do you have to hand code the mappings to any new dependencies?

Comment: This is not really a question to be asking on SO. Try Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do with MEAN.IO is create a custom package

```
mean package customPackageName
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/app.js
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/package.json
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/bower.json
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/.bowerrc
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/README.md
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/server
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/public
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/public/assets
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/public/assets/css
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/public/assets/css/custompackagename.css
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/public/assets/img
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/public/controllers
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/public/controllers/custompackagename.js
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/public/directives
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/public/routes
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/public/routes/custompackagename.js
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/public/services
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/public/services/custompackagename.js
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/public/views
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/public/views/index.html
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/server
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/server/config
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/server/controllers
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/server/models
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/server/routes
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/server/routes/custompackagename.js
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/server/views
   create: ./packages/custom/custompackagename/server/views/index.html
```

After restarting the grunt task a route is then available under /#!/custompackagename/example

The custom package is a module. Within that module you have all the resources loaded that you would expect in an angular project. Essentially each module is a self contained MEAN site. There is a specific dependency chain for these modules. You can make customizations to the directives, services, controllers and views that only affect this module. The MEAN.IO approach creates code that is more reusable but may be a bit more heavy depending on project goals. I can see the potential for redundant bower or node dependencies across multiple MEAN packages.

If you choose to remove a custom package you can type

```
mean uninstall customPackageName
```

It seems like there ought to be a way to avoid some redundant code to reuse across mean package. Documentation and tutorials are kind of sparse at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the general rule of thumb here would be if the generator does not have sub generators for creating controllers, views etc then yes you would have to create them by hand. An alternative is to install the angular generator globally then go ahead and run it in your project then move/map the files accordingly. You could also pull the logic out of some existing generator and modify it to move/map files appropriate to your project structure.